# Hibernate delete cascading isn't working when using sql query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, orm

I have User Entity that is related With Day Entity with OneToMany mapping. I'm trying to delete the user Entity and have it's  days deleted with CascadeType.REMOVE. but when i use sql query this way the cascading doesn't work

```
        Query theQuery =
                currentSession.createQuery(
                        "delete from User where id=:userId");
        theQuery.setParameter("userId", id);

        theQuery.executeUpdate();
```

now when i try to delete the user this way the cascading works and it's days are also deleted :

```
 Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        user gets deleted
        User theUser = findById(id);

        currentSession.remove(theUser);
```

This is the User Entity mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {


    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name ;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
    List<Day> days;
 
}
```

here is my Day Entity mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "day")
public class Day {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id ;


    @Column(name = "date")
    Date date ;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user ;

   
}
```

here is the error I get :

```
: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demo`.`day`, CONSTRAINT `day_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

Comment: Native queries ignore hibernate annotation.

Comment: so should i always read the object before deleting it in order to have it's related entities deleted with cascading? @Jens

Answer (score 0):

In database table "day" you must add on user_id "on delete cascade" when creating.
Or migrate:

```
alter table day add foreign key (ID) references user(ID) on DELETE CASCADE
```